# How to validate routing and break it when not required in angular2

Tags: angular, validation, routes, angular2-routing

I have to add validation on routing. when the user tries to redirect from one page to another I have to check is there any unsaved changes or not. If yes then shows modal to confirm redirection otherwise the user will stay on the same page.

I have tried to work with **canActivate** but it triggered only when the user loads the app not on internal routing.

I am looking for a centralized solution because routing can be done from controller, view or href.

To do that I have subscribed to the **router.events** where I am able to catch all routing events. Now I just **want a way to block routing** and show the modal and also keep track or last routing so that If user click ok then I  can continue routing.

If its a NavigationStart event then I have to break the routing depending on the conditions.

Please suggest is there any way to do that.

**I have to check for every routing happened in the app.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all the routes under a guard and all the routes would be sub routes of the guard.

and also make use of `canDeactivate` to check if the data is saved or not.

```
{ path: 'guard', component:  GuardsComponent , canDeactivate:[CanDeactivateGuard]},
```

**Can Deactivate**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {

  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey my all routing is in child route of app is there is any to way apply it on chile routes